# Custom Close Reasons (August 2013)

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

With the [recent change to the Close system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/25617) we have some more control over what some of our messages say.

We are now allowed to craft our own custom close messages, up to 3. This question is intended to act as a mechanism for gathering proposals and determining which ones the community likes the best, and hates the most. Please post your proposals as answers and vote on the others as you see fit.

Comment: Related: [How can I search for custom off-topic close reasons?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194378/how-can-i-search-for-custom-off-topic-close-reasons) (unfortunately, there is currently no way)

Comment: "This post seems to be an announcement of a sporting event."

Comment: @DeerHunter: I wonder if we should have a related post with AutoReviewComments responses. "I like where this is going, but there are some flaws in implementation." "This post makes no damn sense." "This is a terrible idea. Clearly your mother dropped you as a child."

Comment: A few notes: Try to use bold formatting and link to a meta post in each final close reason. If you look at [ours on Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4506/7433), they all have this. If there isn't a meta post, make one! :)

Answer (score 8):

Pre-filled Option 1:

> Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem.

Comment: And we forwarded your question to the NSA for analysis, they were not pleased.

Answer (score 7):

Pre-filled Option 2:

> Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic as they become obsolete quickly. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: Or ask about what attributes a good solution might contain.

Answer (score 7):

"Default" Off-Topic Close Reason (Shown when no 2 off-topic reasons match on a closed question.)

(However, you cannot explicitly select this reason, strangely enough?? )

> This question does not appear to be about Information Security within the scope defined in the [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yeah, doesn't make sense to me either. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185088/the-default-off-topic-close-reason-cannot-be-selected-from-the-new-close-dialo/185101#185101

Comment: I think that's what the "enter your own comment" OT reason is for

Comment: You can't explicitly select this if you have _three or more_ custom close reasons defined. Strange...

Comment: @MichaelHampton so if we only define *two*, we will have that default back?

Comment: Yes, though I think I'd rather pester the developers until they _leave_ the default present no matter how many close reasons are defined.

Answer (score 6):

> This question is a request for **legal advice**, which is not within the scope of this site. While general discussions of laws are appropriate within the context of IT security, you should always consult a lawyer instead of the Internet when accuracy is important.

Answer (score 5):

We need at least the ability to migrate some things to Serverfault and maybe even Crypto. Currently I feel that some questions are just too complex to migrate over to Super User (like the recent question about configuring a Cisco ASA).

I also feel that some crypto questions we get on here are not really off-topic, however they do fit a lot better on Crypto rather than on Security.SE.

Comment: Migration to Crypto will happen when the site graduates. Migration to SF wasn't justified by the numbers last time round. http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/can-we-finally-sort-out-our-migration-sites/1152#1152

Comment: What's the correct way to do it then? Flag it for moderation attention and add a comment to say it would be better on SF?

Comment: Yes, flag for migration if you're sure it would fit on SF. Moderators can migrate any question to any site, except that questions that are older than 60 days cannot be migrated at all.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-filled Option 3:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).